# How to add validation for a list in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class InvitationViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string InvitationName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string RSVPStat { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Guests> guests { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add some validation for the List of Guests, is it possible to use data annotations for this or is there some other way?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, generally in MVC you add data annotations to your ViewModel for validation.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I want a specific set of validation for the view model, that is different to the model class validation.  How can I add the validation for the List<Guests>?

Comment: You answered the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is a little unclear, I'll round the bases. You can add some validation to the list itself, if that's what you're looking for. That pretty much just includes `Required`, which would validate that the list has at least one item:

```
[Required]
public List<Guests> Guests { get; set; }
```

*The keyword `virtual` allows a property, method or field to be overridden by a subclass. Most likely, you saw this on your entity and figured you need the same here in your view model. The reason entities use `virtual` on reference and navigation properties is that Entity Framework creates proxy classes of your entities in order to provide lazy-loading functionality. The proxies (which are just subclasses) override the reference and navigation properties to insert the lazy-loading code necessary.*

If you're talking about adding validation attributes to the properties of the actual `Guest` class, you cannot do that just for the sake of a view model. Any validation you add to `Guest` will be for any use of `Guest`. There's nothing stopping you from also implementing a `GuestViewModel` or similar class, though, which you could then add whatever validation you like to.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  I want to add validation attributes to the property of guest.  I will try your suggestion of creating a GuestViewModel.

Comment: In general is not so good idea to use your data store objects directly in your views. So the GuestViewModel is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to validate each guest? In that case mark Guest up with Data annotations. If you want a validation on the list itself (i.e. number of guests), you can write you own ValidationAttribute, or you can implement IValidateableObject on your model.

Edit: if your view model requires different validation, create a GuestViewModel and mark it up with the required validation.

Comment: Yes validate each guest.  Guest is marked up with annotations, but the view model requires different validation.  For example, the Model Guest class has properties that can be null.  But when the ViewModel is submitted the same fields are required.

Comment: I edited my answer: sounds like you need a GuestViewModel based on Guest.  At our project this is our routine practice, since domain models and viewmodels are almost always different.